# What might cause an MUI Snackbar to not generate the correct class names?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to show a notification on my Gatsby blog [when the service worker updates](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/add-offline-support-with-a-service-worker/#displaying-a-message-when-a-service-worker-updates), using an [MUI Snackbar toast](https://material-ui.com/components/alert/#toast). Sometimes the toast doesn't have any styling, and looks like this:

[image: Snackbar without style]

It should look like this:

[image: Correct Snackbar toast]

I can see that the `<Snackbar>` and `MUIAlert` don't output the correct classes on their `div`s.

The code is below:

```js
export default function Layout({ children }: { children: ReactNode }): ReactElement {
  const [toastOpenState, setToastOpenState] = React.useState(isBrowser() && Boolean(localStorage.getItem('serviceWorkerUpdated')));

  function handleToastClose(): void {
    setToastOpenState(false);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <TopNav/>

      <Snackbar className="toast"
        anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'center' }}
        open={toastOpenState}
        onClose={handleToastClose}
        TransitionComponent={Transition}
      >
        <MuiAlert severity="success" variant="filled" elevation={6} onClose={handleToastClose}>
          A new version is available.
          <Button onClick={() => {
            localStorage.removeItem('serviceWorkerUpdated');
            window.location.reload();
          }}>Reload</Button>
        </MuiAlert>
      </Snackbar>

      <div style={{ flex: 1, margin: '0 1em' }}>
        {children}
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to move setting the `open` state of the toast to `true` from an `onEffect` hook:

```js
  const [toastOpenState, setToastOpenState] = React.useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('serviceWorkerUpdated'))
      setToastOpenState(true);
  }, []);

  // Called by clicking the close button
  function handleToastClose(): void {
    setToastOpenState(false);
  }

  return (
    <>
      ... same stuff
    </>
  );
}
```